# Javadoc for custom tags in JSP

Tags: jsp, javadoc, jsp-tags, custom-tag

I am creating a custom JSP tag using a class which extends TagSupport and a tld. I want to create a javadoc such that when a designer uses these tags, like for example in eclipse, on ctrl+space (in windows), the designer must get tag info and same thing should happen for each atribute in the tag. I tried giving /** .. */ in class, it did not work. How to do this ? If there is an easier tool, please mention tutorial link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should go in `<description>` element of the `<tag>` and `<attribute>` elements in the `.tld` file.

E.g.

```
<tag>
    <description>This tag does foo.</description>
    <name>foo</name>
    ...
    <attribute>
        <description>Sets the value of foo.</description>
        <name>value</name>
        ...
    </attribute>
</tag>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I had to change the <description> to <info> for tag description. For attribute <description> worked. Strange

Comment: Then your editor is using it the wrong way or it is not using the tld file version you think it is using (cache and so on, restart editor to be sure).

Comment: Data Type always shows "CDATA" for me. Know of any way to include it without duplicating in the attribute description?